# Does indentation matter in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

Does indentation matter in Verilog HDL as it does in Python ?
Or is it more like C++ where all it matters is if you have correctly put the { and } blocks ?

Edit: This is something written in my textbook:

```
always @(A or B or select)
  if(select == 1) m_out = A;
  else m_out = B;
```

It seems here that the block is defined by indentation. Why is it so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, indentation doesn't matter in Verilog (as extra blanks, tabs and newlines). Instead of using indentation, it has `begin` and `end` keywords (and `endmodule`) to delimit blocks. So, all you need is to correctly put these keywords in place. For example:

```
always
 begin
   clk = 0;
   #1;
   clk = 1;
   #1;
 end
```

In your example, the `if` and `else` blocks, only have *one* statement each, so you don't need to use `begin`/`end` keywords (there is a similar thing in C). Also, `always` block only contains one `if-else` block, so we don't need `begin`/`end` there, either. If any of these blocks had more than 1 statement, we had to use `begin`/`end`. For example:

```
always @(A or B or select)
  if(select == 1) m_out = A;
  else 
    begin
        m_out = B;
        m_out_2 = A;
    end
```

Comment: thanks, I was confused by the semicolon after the if part of the if-else statement. I thought that the if statement ended there and the else was another statement.